# Agrupar varios registros de una tabla

Tags: sql-server

Tengo le siguiente  tabla con números de guía hay varios números de guía que son iguales pero tiene un producto diferente o igual como puedo agrupar estos números para cuando haga la consulta me muestre solo que hay uno  es decir si hay 3 productos con el numero de guía 5544 y o tres productos con el numero de guía 4444 me muestre solo que hay 2 o sea 5544 y 4444

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo esta consulta

```
SELECT NumeroGuia,COUNT(NumeroGuia) AS NumeroGuia, TxInvPTCanasta,TxInvPTProducto FROM [dbo].[tbl_guia_cansta]
GROUP BY TxInvPTCanasta,FechaInsert,NumeroGuia,TxInvPTProducto
ORDER BY FechaInsert DESC
```

Que me arroja lo siguiente me dice que hay  2  de 4444 por que el producto es el mismo PT-1112 pero hay otro con el 4444 y lo deja por fuera por que no tiene el mismo producto crearía yo, como puedo agrupar estos números de guía independientemente que tengan diferentes productos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tenés que quitar `TxInvPTProducto` de tu `SELECT` y del `GROUP BY`, si de última querés este dato, podes aplicar un `MAX(TxInvPTProducto)` al menos para obtener uno

Comment: Pero así quite el TxInvPTProducto sigue apareciendo igual la consulta

Comment: Que resultato esperarias?

Comment: No entiendo tu comentario, lo quitaste y sigue apareciendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que se agrupe de la forma que deseas lo cual seria por "NumeroGuia" debes quitar las columnas "TxInvPTCanasta" y "TxInvPTProducto" de tu SELECT ya que sus datos no son iguales por lo que no se agruparan como lo deseas.

Por otro lado debes quitar del GROUP BY las columnas que no utilices, que son "TxInvPTCanasta", "FechaInsert" y "TxInvPTProducto" ya que la consulta solo agrupa las columnas que estén en tu SELECT.

También debes quitar tu "ORDER BY FechaInsert" ya que no tienes esta columna en tu SELECT por lo que no afectara el orden en que se muestren las filas.

Tu consulta quedaría de esta manera:

```
SELECT NumeroGuia, COUNT(NumeroGuia) AS NumeroGuia FROM [dbo].[tbl_guia_cansta]
GROUP BY NumeroGuia;
```